# Show video when first frame is loaded (no black screen)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller

I need to find a way to display the view of a `MPMoviePlayerController` after the first frame of the video is cached.

My App shows the first frame of the video as a `png` and I want the video then to be shown without the screen going black for a second. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Display that image as a view-overlay on top of your `MPMoviePlayerController` by adding it as a subview of `MPMoviePlayerController.view`.

Once the video has started the playback (use the  `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification` to react upon that), hide / remove your overlay.

Comment: The MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification fires immediately and thus the image is being hidden before the video actually starts and so I get the black screen